# usbnet not working with 19.10 Raspberry Pi 4 (2G DRAM)

Tags: networking, usb, raspberrypi

I've tried to get IP over USB working on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 2G of memory. usbnet works fine with Raspbian on this same hardware setup

usrcfg.txt (absence of dr_mode=peripheral doesn't seem to make a difference)

```
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral
```

nobtcmd.txt:

```
net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait modules-load=dwc2,g_ether fixrtc 

root@ubuntu:/boot/firmware# ip a show eth0                                     
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group defa
ult qlen 1000                                                                   
    link/ether dc:a6:32:02:a2:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                          
    inet 192.168.1.132/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0           
       valid_lft 85802sec preferred_lft 85802sec                                
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe02:a277/64 scope link                               
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                  
root@ubuntu:/boot/firmware# ip a show usb0                                     
Device "usb0" does not exist.                                                   
root@ubuntu:/boot/firmware#  lsmod | grep g_ether                              
g_ether                16384  0                                                 
usb_f_rndis            45056  1 g_ether                                         
u_ether                32768  2 usb_f_rndis,g_ether                             
libcomposite           77824  2 usb_f_rndis,g_ether                             
root@ubuntu:/boot/firmware#
```

I think this is a clue to the problem:

```
[    9.117963] udc-core: couldn't find an available UDC - added [g_ether] to list
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I would like to get this working as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the kernel config did not include it.  The kernel needs to be rebuilt after setting CONFIG_USB_DWC2_DUAL_ROLE and CONFIG_USB_OTG.